# jquery autocomplete invalid 'in' operand

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

After several hours trying to get jquery autocomplete to work I'm waiving the white flag. I need help. At one point I was getting results back but they weren't formatted the way I needed them. I switched from a simple string function for converting the List<> to the c# JavaScriptSerializer and that's when I started getting the invalid 'in' operand error. So I moved down from jquery 1.11 to 1.8 and got past the that error. But now I can't seem to pull the correct values out of the response... undefined. If I alert(data.d) I do get back the json data and I did validate it using http://jsonlint.com.

Someone... please help me!

**Update**

I got it working by first parsing the json:

```
success: function(data) {
    var d = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
    response($.map(d, function (item) {
        return {
            id: item.Id,
            name: item.Name
        }
    }))
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: No idea if this is causing the error, but the `data` parameter for `$.ajax()` is meant to be either a serialized string (`'var1=foo&var2=bar&var3=baz'`) or a plain object (not a JSON string). So instead of `"{'term':'" + request.term + "'}"` (a JSON string), it should be `{term: request.term}` (a JS object). Not sure if jQuery is able to handle it as you have it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made the change you suggested and I get the following error: "Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: term." It seems to be making it passed this point the way I had it originally as results are returned.

Comment: Did you remove the quotes around the curly braces? In any case, it seems like jQuery was probably handling your JSON string properly, since it recognizes that it is a JSON string and gives an error when you removed the single quotes around `'term'`. Highly unlikely that this was the issue.

Comment: If I hard code the json string on the page as var d = [{"Id":101,"Name":"Lorem ipsum dolor"},{"Id":102,"Name":"Lorem ipsum dolor"},{"Id":103,"Name":"Lorem ipsum dolor"}] and update success to response($.map(d, function (item) { it works. I also had to change ui.item.Name to ui.item.name as well as Id as suggested below by Rohan Kumar but it still isn't working with the ajax call. So what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `ui.item.name` in place of `ui.item.Name` same for `Id` like,

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    alert('you have selected ' + ui.item.name + ' Id: ' + ui.item.id);
    return false;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/bcC2p/)

Comment: Nope, still just getting a bunch of 'undefined' in the dropdown

Comment: If is works in `error` then obviously it should work in `success callback` see http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/bcC2p/1/